# Need to Select a random letter in a string and change it

Tags: java, string

Could someone show me how I would input a string into a method and it would select one letter of the string and change it to a letter I choose. For example, I would call `ChangeString(hello)` and it would return a string that changed one letter like `"Hel_o"`.

**(Edit)** I've tried setCharAt() and putting in a random number, but i dont know how to make it change just one letter and leave the rest of the string alone and give me the changed letter and the new string.

**(Edit 2)** Alright I seem to have figured somthing. Thanks everyone!

**This isn't homework, This is an app I'm working on in Eclipse for the market! I just needed Help.**

Comment: Ditto -- with [link!](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Otherwise how will we know what you're doing wrong, what you need help with?

Comment: Ive tried setCharAt() and putting in a random number, but i dont know how to make it change just one letter and leave the rest of the string alone and give me the changed letter.

Comment: Consider looping through the characters or flooring your random number and accessing the string as an array.

Comment: please you `changeString()` and not `ChangeString()`, according to the java conventions, a method name should start with a lower-case

Comment: I've not heard of the `setCharAt()` letter. Are you using a String object here or something else like a StringBuffer? Please show your code attempt in your question above as well as any error messages by editing the question and posting the code and messages. We can help you format the code so that it's readable in the forum.

Comment: I have it like that in my code.

Comment: Again, there is no `setCharAt()` method.

Comment: mark your question answered instead of editing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, convert the string into a character array. Then, generate a random integer between 0 and the length of the string. Set the character at that array index to an underscore. Return a new string with the modified character array.

```
String changeString(String s)
{
   char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
   int rand = (int)(Math.random() * s.length());
   characters[rand] = '_';
   return new String(characters);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be better then my fix, Thanks!

Comment: You ought to post just a hint but not a complete solution: after all, the question is definitely a homework-type one. So, having the complete answer doesn't help the OP to learn how to code.

Comment: This isn't homework, This is an app I'm working on in Eclipse for the market! I just need Help.

Comment: @Xwire: It has nothing to do with this being homework or not. You learn more if *you* find the solution from our suggestions, rather then if someone spoon feeds it to you. Period. You learn more if you show us your code attempt and we suggest how to improve it.

Comment: Some people learn better by example and will think about problems differently in the future. I posted a complete answer to differ the OP's confusion with erencan's wrong (and now deleted) answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I'm self taught, I learned everything I know by looking at examples and understanding how they work. I wouldn't have learned anything if I didnt see the codes at first, many people learn by example best.

Comment: I'm self-taught too. Surely you can't disagree that it is best to wait for review of *some* of his code attempt before giving solution though. I don't see indication anywhere that this guy even seriously tried at all other than to make up some method that doesn't exist in the API. So what are we teaching him? That it's better to beg for a solution than to learn to study the API first?

Comment: Note though that point is taken and I have deleted my down-vote.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `setCharAt()` method - see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). This is because Strings in Java are *immutable* - you can't change them, you can only create new ones.

You can create a new String from chunks of the old one (using the `substring()` method) and stick your new character in the middle, or you can create a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), which *can* be modified, then regenerate a String from that.

Answer (score 1):

Here I believe this does what you're looking for.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random; 
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 
public class XRandom{ 
public static void changeString(String entry,char change){ 
int length=entry.length();
char[] cArray = entry.toCharArray();
    cArray[randomNumber(0,length)]=change;
System.out.println(cArray);

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a String:");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String name = null;
       try {
         name = br.readLine();
       } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Error!");
         System.exit(1);
       }
       char un='_';
       changeString(name,un);
    }


    public static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return min + (new Random()).nextInt(max - min);
    }
}
```

just wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `StringBuffer` class help you with its `charAt()` method.