# Replace Random Number with "X"

Tags: random

I have been tasked to replace a random number in a string with "X." The only way I am allowed to do it is with Math.random. The method also can have no parameters. This is in a class that is used in a separate pre-assembled driver. This is the code I have written:

```
public ComputerMicrobe mutate()
{
    int a = (int)(Math.random() * (0 - dNACode.length()));
    String b = Integer.toString(a);
    dNACode = dNACode.replace(a, "X");
    return this;

} // End mutate
```

I am completely lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please tag a language

Comment: what is `dNACode` and `ComputerMicrobe` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are supposed to generate a random position in the string and replace whatever is at that position with an `"X"`. (I'm also guessing that this is Java.) Your code doesn't come close to doing what you want. First, `a` is going to be negative because `Math.random()` is a random `double` value between 0 and 1.0 and `(0 - dNACode.length())` evaluates to a negative number. Second, [`replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Math.html) does a replacement based on a substring match, not any kind of position-based substitution. So if `dNACode` was something like `"AUUGAC"` then your code would be trying to replace all instances of `"-3"` with `"X"`.

Try this instead:

```
static Random sRand = new Random();
public ComputerMicrobe mutate()
{
    int a = sRand.nextInt(dNACode.length());
    dNACode = dNACode.substring(0, a) + "X" + dNACode.substring(a+1);
    return this;

} // End mutate
```

This sets `a` to the index of the character to be replaced and then assembles a new value for `dNACode` from the substrings strictly before and after that position, with `"X"` added in between.

Here I'm using an instance of `java.util.Random` rather than `Math.random()` to generate random positions. (The `Random` object is created once and shared by all calls to `mutate()`.) `Random` has the very useful `nextInt(int)` method that generates a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and its argument (exclusive).

I don't know how much control you have over the rest of the code, but I would strongly suggest declaring `dNACode` to be a `StringBuider` rather than a `String`. Then you could dispense with all the substring operations and replace the assignment to `dNACode` with:

```
dNACode.replace(a, 'X');
```

Or you could use a `char[]` and simply do:

```
dNACode[a] = 'X';
```

Particularly if you are doing a lot of calls to `mutate()`, this will drastically reduce the amount of garbage being generated. You can always call `dNACode.toString()` (or `new String(dNACode)`) whenever you need an actual `String` instead of a `CharSequence` (or `char[]`). (Note that you usually can print a `StringBuilder` or `char[]` directly, without constructing a `String` yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it seems that your `String b` is always = `-{LENGTH_OF_STRING}` . Thus no string will be replaced.

I assume you are using Java, refer this similar question it can help you : [Need to Select a random letter in a string and change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557212/need-to-select-a-random-letter-in-a-string-and-change-it)